# Automatically create data frames based on factor levels of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some fake case data with a manager id, type, and location. I'd like to automatically create data frames with the average number of cases a manager has at a given location.

```
# create fake data
manager_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
type <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
location <- c("Beach", "Beach", "Beach", "Beach", "Beach", "City", "City", "City", "Farm", "Farm", "Farm", "Farm", "Farm", "Farm", "City")
manager_id <- data.frame(manager_id)
type <- data.frame(type)
location <- data.frame(location)
df <- cbind(manager_id, type, location)
```

After creating fake data, I created a function that finds this average. The function works.

```
avgs_function <- function(dat){
dat1 <- dat %>% group_by(manager_id) %>% summarise(total = n())
total <- mean(dat1$total)
total <- round(total, 0)
total
}
```

I then loop through each location, create data frames using the avgs_function, and store them in a list. Then I call the data frames into my global environment. Something is going wrong here that I can't figure out. The weird thing is that is was working fine yesterday.

```
df_list <- unique(df$location) %>%
           set_names() %>%
           map(~avgs_function(df))
names(df_list) <- paste0(names(df_list), "_avg")
list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Right now, the code is giving these values:

```
Beach_avg = 5
City_avg = 5
Farm_avg = 5
```

I would like:

```
Beach_avg = 5
City_avg = 2
Farm_avg = 3
```

I believe the issue is happening with the purrr package. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @akrun Sorry if I am still misunderstanding but I do get an average of 2 for city. 

city <- df %>% filter(location == "City")
city <- city %>% group_by(manager_id) %>% summarise(total = n())
mean(city$total)

I'm hoping to have three separate vectors where Beach_avg = 5, City_avg = 2, Farm_avg = 3.

Comment: I think you need `df %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise(n = table(manager_id)) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(n), .groups = 'drop')`. I was thinking that you need it the other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `purrr` at all (just `dplyr`): this gets your desired output

```r
result <-(df 
  %>% count(manager_id, location) 
  %>% group_by(location) 
  %>% summarise(across(n, mean))
)
```

(although without the `_avg` added to the location names: you could add `mutate(across(location, paste0, "_avg"))` (or something with `glue`) if you wanted)

This also doesn't create the separate variables you wanted (although obviously you can add more stuff e.g. `with(result, setNames(list(n), location)) %>% list2env()`, but in general workflows that populate your global workspace with a bunch of different named variables are a bad idea - collections like this can usually be handled better by keeping them inside a list/data frame/tibble ...

Comment: thank you! This code created the separate data frames I needed.

result %>% split(.$location) %>% list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)

Comment: if this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...